# How do I add padding to this <textarea>?

Tags: html, css

The  is not resizable and It looks all weird and is not lined up :(

[image: What is looks like now (the amount obviously)]

The amount is the textarea because I need it to be a textarea, not an input because I need to use .innerHTML in javascript to change the amount value when I click the arrows.

```css
textarea {
        width: 21%;
        margin-left: 12px;
        font-size: 18px;
        padding-left: 1.5em;
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: #202023;
        border-radius: 10px;
        border: none;
        color: white;
    }
```

```html
<textarea id="myTextArea" placeholder="Amount"></textarea>
```

I would also love to have the textarea align with the other input/button!

Thanks for your time!! :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add padding to a textarea without causing the width to increase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4180827/how-can-i-add-padding-to-a-textarea-without-causing-the-width-to-increase)

Comment: Placing those arrows on textarea with position:absolute  may help to align the textarea with textbox and button.

Comment: can you post the full snippet so we can see the full css design which renders to answer your second query particularly. Usually floating the text input and area should do the job of alignment.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Bootstrap. Ex:

```
<div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        Enter link input field
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        Your textarea
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        Create button
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But bootstrap is not mentioned in tags?

Comment: You need to explicitly import bootstrap into your project.. I know it may be a hassle for you, but I promise you its gonna be worth the reduced workload that you are gonna face, given that you style/position the tags with "width:21%"..

Answer (score 0):

Are the elements u want align in a single div?

try css float for textarea. Or better if applied to all elements that need to be aligned.